# Enums and ternary strange behavior in gcc7

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, enums

We are now testing compiling some Qt code under QtCreator with the newer gcc 7.3 available in Ubuntu 18 (we were previously using gcc 4.9.3 under Ubuntu 16).

Qt provides an `enum` thus:

```
enum CheckState {
    Unchecked,
    PartiallyChecked,
    Checked
};
```

Now, when we use the ternary operator with this:

```
QVariant MyClass::MyFunc(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    return (someCondition ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
}
```

then `gcc` complains (with a warning, but we treat warnings as errors):

```
prog.cpp:999:99:
    error: passing ‘Qt::CheckState’ chooses ‘int’
        over ‘uint {aka unsigned int}’ [-Werror=sign-promo]
```

We can get around the issue with:

```
return (someCondition ? Qt::Checked : static_cast<int>(Qt::Unchecked));
```

but I'm not sure why that should be necessary.

Since these are coming from exactly the same `enum`, they should be the same type, no? I know that there are potential issues where the two possible values are different types, but I can't understand why this type casting needs to be done in this case.

The values are `{0, 1, 2}` from the `enum` and I would have thought the *exact same* type negated any possibility for conversion.

The only possibility I can think of is the fact that the zero value of the enumeration is being treated as unsigned for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lieu of an MCVE I am assuming the context is something like:

```
struct S
{
    S(int);
    S(unsigned int);
};

S foo()
{
    return (1 ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
}
```

which [produces warning in gcc 7.3](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PAsV9n):

> warning: passing `Qt::CheckState` chooses `int` over `unsigned int` [-Wsign-promo]

---

The warning relates to the implicit conversion of value of type `enum CheckState` to integer.  There is valid implicit conversion to both `int` and `unsigned int`, and overload resolution selects `int`.

Apparently the rationale for the warning is that some older versions of gcc selected `unsigned int` in this scenario , but gcc 7 follows the Standard and selects `int`.

Your fix works because the second and third operands are brought to a common type of `int` before overload resolution occurs (it is not anything to do with which enumerator you chose).

Perhaps an appropriate fix would be to apply `static_cast<int>` to the whole conditional, not just one operand.

Comment: M.M., I think you may be right. I've been trying to get an MCVE going with return value of int and unsigned int but the failure doesn't appear. The actual code returns a `QVariant` which almost certainly has constructors for many types (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), ***including*** `QVariant(int val)` and `QVariant(uint val)`.

Comment: Just out of interest, would you consider this a bug? It seems to me that the compiler should *not* be treating the values as different types if they come from the same enum.

Comment: @paxdiablo They're not treated as different types. The result of the conditional has type `enum CheckState` and the warning comes from the attempt to implicitly convert `enum CheckState` to `QVariant` . You probably get the same warning if you change the code to `return Qt::Checked;`

Comment: Correct. Ah, I think I see now. It's actually nothing to do with the ternary, just a warning that gcc is preferring one conversion over another, something that's logically *after* the selection process. Removing either constructor fixes the issue (not an option with real Qt of course, it's not our code). Casting the entire expression we're returning also fixes it, and allows me to approve the PR with my OCD tendencies :-) Thanks for your assist.

Comment: FWIW, we went with `return static_cast<int>(1 ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);`.